# MySQL chaining WHERE IN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a order table that contains and order number, customer id and agent id. Then theres a customer table with a id and a agent table with a id.

I need to get all the customer ids that have an order from both agent id 'a03' and agent id 'a05'

Right now I'm trying to get all the customer ids but only the ones that appear in both a list from customer ids from agent 'a03' and a list from agent'a05'.

Chaining the second WHERE IN doesn't work.

```
select customer.cid 
from customer 
where customer.cid in 
    (select order1.cid 
     from order1 
     inner join agent on order1.aid=agent.aid 
     where agent.aid="a05") 
 and 
    (select order1.cid 
    from order1 
    inner join agent on order1.aid=agent.aid 
    where agent.aid="a03");
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to return only those customers who appear for both agents.  If that is the case, then you can use group by:

```
select c.cid
from customer c
    join order1 o on c.cid = o.cid
    join agent a on o.aid = a.aid
where a.aid in ('a05','a03')
group by c.cid
having count(distinct a.aid) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `and` with `or customer.cid in`:

```
select customer.cid 
from customer 
where customer.cid in 
    (select order1.cid 
     from order1 
     inner join agent on order1.aid=agent.aid 
     where agent.aid="a05") 
 or customer.cid in 
    (select order1.cid 
    from order1 
    inner join agent on order1.aid=agent.aid 
    where agent.aid="a03");
```

Or shorter version:

```
select customer.cid 
from customer 
where customer.cid in 
    (select order1.cid 
     from order1 
     inner join agent on order1.aid=agent.aid 
     where agent.aid="a05" or agent.aid="a03")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want this, if i'm correct there is no need for the second and/subselect, it will only add more overhead.

```
select customer.cid 
from customer 
where customer.cid in 
    (select order1.cid 
     from order1 
     inner join agent on order1.aid=agent.aid 
     where agent.aid="a05" or agent.aid="a03")
```

Comment: I think this will only get the customer ids where they appear in either an order with agent a05 or a05. Rather than customers who appear have orders using both a03 and a05

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the customer ids why don't you use this

```
select cid from order1 inner join agent on order1.aid = agent.aid where agent.aid in ("a05", "a03");
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I've got this right...

```
SELECT c.cid 
  FROM customer c
  JOIN order1 o1
    ON o1.cid = c.cid
  JOIN agent a 
    ON a.aid = o1.aid
 WHERE a.aid IN('a05','a03');
```

?